# Confusion about the rhythm I use

Tags: rhythm

This might be a odd question but on guitar I have this lick where I would play 3 notes with the same distance to each other between the strokes and then I would play 4 notes slightly faster (with the first note of this set of 4 having the same distance to the last note of the set of 3 but then all notes in the set of 4 have a shorter distance). I'm relatively new to theory and notation but can I assume what I play could be notated as a triplet of 2 quarter notes + 4 eight notes ? If so what rhythm is best suited underneath it ?

EDIT:
Since I have no possibility of recording myself right now I tried to visualize what I mean:
[image]

1. The time passed by the blue bar and the red bar is equal.
2. If I would play 8 notes with the same distance between each stroke I
   would get the pattern of line 2.
3. The way I play it the first 3
   notes take up as much time as the 4 notes do and I have 7 strokes
   total.

Comment: This may be really hard to answer by this description. Do you have a link to video or recording of you playing this?

Comment: Edited my question to provide a better understanding.

Comment: If it is in 4/4 I'd say it's triplet crotchets followed by four quavers.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you mean:

Dotted eighth note, dotted eighth note, eighth note, eighth note, eighth note, eighth note, eighth note?

[image]

*If this is the case, note that the first 3 aren't played with the exact same timing (the gap between the 3rd and the 1st note of the second group of 4 notes is too small to be a triplet)*

Comment: Alternatively, those opening three pitches could be a quarter-note triplet.

Comment: It feels like the first 3 notes belong together and the last 4 notes belong together, so I'm guessing that its triplet + 4 eightn notes. I edited my question with a visualization of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

If the entire graph you have there is one measure, or in 4/4 time, 4 beats (which equals one measure) then red and blue are half notes. And in 4/4 half notes get two beats each.

The second row has 8 notes in the measure. Easiest way to think about that is that you are playing eight notes. Anything divided by 8 would get you eights. But you can also think there are two for each beat. One beat 4/4 would be quarter notes and a quarter note divided in half is eight notes.

The third row has three notes for each half note. Anytime you have 3 to a unit you are most likely dealing with triplets. In this case you have what is called quarter note triplets.

Hope that makes sense.